# Updating Java and JRE are causing many errors in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse to program Android applications, and when I opened the program yesterday, it popped up an error saying I need to install JRE - I've downloaded the JRE and installed it - when during the installation I got a message saying that the JAVA version I have on the computer (Version 7) is too old for the JRE (Version 8), and that I need to update the JAVA also.
I did so, and then opened up the Eclipse again - And all of the projects,that before worked great, are now full with errors.
I tried installing all of the SDK updates - didn't work, also tried uninstalling Eclipse and re-install it - also didn't work.

The errors I get are: "XXX cannot be resolved to a type" - in amost every single line in the project.

How do I fix it??
Thank you!!

Comment: Try to lean and reuild your project, and check if the "installed JRE" in your eclipse. "Window"-->"Preferences"-->"java"

Comment: Android Studio, my man. It is dedicated to Android Development, and is much easier to use.

Comment: Eh, there's no dedicated Android development IDE per se. An IDE is an IDE; plus Android Studio is a fork of IntelliJ, and IntelliJ has been used to develop many other Java technologies beside Android.

Answer (score 0):

android development tool(adt) are install.. and all update SDK and then import an old program.. Ithink  then  work.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check that your java build path is functioning properly. This kind of error for me usually means that eclipse cannot find the JRE installation.

Form eclipse you can go to `Project->Properties` and check for any errors there. Any inconsistency there  would cause all your projects to fail.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need the JDK installation, *not* JRE. Second, Android currently supports up to Java v7, which means you'll need to get JDK v7 from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html). Make sure you download the correct 32-bit or 64-bit JDK version for your operating system.

Also, ensure your Android SDK and Android Development Tools (ADT) are on the **same** released version. Different versions of Android SDK and ADT can lead to many unforseen problems.

Comment: I've uninstalled all of my JRE, JDK versions I'd had and installed only Version 7.45 both JDK and JRE, but I still have the same errors. the one that shows up in the Console is this one: EclipseWorkSpace\MobileExcersice2\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.*'. (Where the * is different in each error - Light, Light.DarkActionBar).

Comment: That's a different error to what you had posted originally. It looks like you're using the appcompat v7 in your project. If you do, to resolve the error you've got, open `project.properties` file in your appcompat v7 project and change the target to `target.target=android-21` and save the file. Then clean all Android projects. This should fix all errors.